# Roaming turned off but icon shows on?

Tags: 8.0, lumia

I'm using a Nokia Lumia 625 with Windows Phone 8. I currently have a small triangle icon [image] which I understand is an indication that roaming is activated. But when I check the settings, it says roaming is disabled. Is this a bug or something

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable roming. You can only choose if the data connection will be used during roming. Thus, while roming, the icon will always be there.
The option in the network settings just lets you choose if the mobile data connection will be active or disabled during roaming.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart your phone and make sure that roaming and data connection are turned off